# Numerical methods for complex integrals?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods

are there numerical methods to evaluate COMPLEX integrals like this ?

$$ \int_{3-i\infty}^{3+i\infty}f(s)ds $$

or to evaluate integrals over a curve on the complex plane

$$ \int_{C}f(z)dz $$

for the case of real valued integrals we know lots of methods but how about complex integrals ??

Comment: Are those holomorphic or meromorphic functions? For the second one, it is almost the same as the real case. For the first one, you need to have an holomorphic function to have it well defined